# Android: Customized List view with varying image views

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if the following is possible with custom list views/adapters

I want to create the following row for a list view

IV -> IV -> IV -> CHECKBOX

However, my problem is that the amount of Image views will vary. For example in one row there could be 3 IV but another row may have 1 or 2. So basically the contents of each row can vary.

IV -> IV -> CHECKBOX

IV -> CHECKBOX

I would like some advice if this is possible please

Comment: Ill wait for you image, but I may have some ideas!  Will there ever be a time when there will be enough images, to make a row wider than the screen can handle?

Comment: You need to make one row with max possible no of imageviews(3 in your case) and one checkbox now inside getview() those imgviews you dont want for that row make theme Gone

Answer (score 0):

I think listview wont help you for your requirement. Rather than listview use viewgroup like linearlayout & add images, checkboxes dynamically according to your data..

After completing each row, add to your respective parent layout.

It may help...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Use a custom adapter, and in getView method place the logic that decide what XML to use as a layout

Answer (score 0):

I would think to do something like the following:

```
ScrollView (Vertical)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| LinearLayout (Vertical)                                                            |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| | ScrollView (Horizontal)                                                        | |
| | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ | |
| | | LinearLayout (Horizontal)                                                  | | |
| | | -------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | |
| | | | ImageView                                                              | | | |
| | | | ---------- ----------          /                                       | | | |
| | | | |        | |        |         /                                        | | | |
| | | | |        | |        |        /                                         | | | |
| | | | |        | |        |    \  /                                          | | | |
| | | | ---------- ----------     \/                                           | | | |
| | | -------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | |
| | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ | |
| |                                                                                | |
| | ScrollView (Horizontal)                                                        | |
| | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ | |
| | | LinearLayout (Horizontal)                                                  | | |
| | | -------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | |
| | | | ImageView                                                              | | | |
| | | | ---------- ---------- ----------          /                            | | | |
| | | | |        | |        | |        |         /                             | | | |
| | | | |        | |        | |        |        /                              | | | |
| | | | |        | |        | |        |    \  /                               | | | |
| | | | ---------- ---------- ----------     \/                                | | | |
| | | -------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | |
| | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ | |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The horizontal scrollers are there just in case you have enough images to make the content wider than the screen, same with the vertical just in case your content is taller than the screen.

Add your layouts, scrollviews, and imageviews dynamically